# php : repost the parameters

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP to repost all the $_POST variables without having to create hidden fields ?

page1.php has form with many form elements and post them to page2.php

page2.php reposts to page3.php without having to recreate all hidden fields

Comment: You could do it with `$_GET`, but I don't think you can with `$_POST`.

Comment: They should be restored anywhere to be accessible in next page

Comment: Did you try or consider [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) ?

Comment: instead of abstract forms an enumerated pages you should describe real matter. Otherwise you will get no real answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can store the values in a [**session**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). `page2.php` sets them, `page3.php` reads them (and optionally deletes them).

Answer (score 0):

Not through POST alone, but you could, on page2.php copy each of the POST variables into a SESSION variable which is then obtained in page3.php